# Non-GPL alternative to FFMPEG?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

From reading about the GPL I have concluded that is not possible to publish an app on the App Store using a library like ffmpeg.

Is there another library than ffmpeg for converting .flv to audio files that is not under GPL license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why does this come up so often? there is information on the ffmpeg site explaining how to deploy ffmpeg apps on iOS and the license ramifications.

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1229

As long as you use the lgpl/gpl version of ffmpeg you should be fine.

It was more of a grey area in 2009 when I first helped port first ffmpeg apps but now there are countless apps in the appstore.

Its important that you abide by the LGPL license other than that you should be fine.

Comment: sure, I know of no other free api that can do encoding/decoding, and the commercial ones are expensive.

Comment: do u know any tutorial about it or is there any documentation?

Comment: you mean ffmpeg, I don't have info on alternatives. First starting point should be ffmpeg.org , lots of info, since you specifically mention flv you might look at my webstreamX_flv_demo for some help https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/WebStreamX_flv_demo, there also is live555 , like I mentioned there is a lot more info now then there used to be. We tend to try to stay ahead of the game though.